# How to remove manufacturer list from Advanced Search?

Tags: magento-1.7, module, extensions, theme

I want to remove manufacturer list from advanced search section. Is there any section available in magento backend end to disable or any way other way to disable it. Can anyone tell how to disable it ?
Sample URL: http://localhost.lst/index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the attribute in the backend and set the flag "used in advanced search" to "no". A reindex mai be needed.